# Find all files on sd card

Tags: android, sd-card

I want to find all files stored on sdCard. I used this code:

```
List<File> dir = new ArrayList<File>();
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

   File root = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

    scan(root); // find root directories

    for (File f : dir) { // find in root...
       scan(f);
    }

    Log.i("files", "" + files.size());
    Log.i("dir", "" + dir.size());


}

 public void scan (File path) {

    for (File f : path.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            files.add(f);
        }
        else {
            dir.add(f);
        }
    }
}
```

But I have problem with this exception: "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException" 
I change list (dir) and loop it. The ListIterator doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add to a list while you're iterating over it. Try this instead:

```
List<File> dir = new ArrayList<File>();
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

   File root = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

    List<File> rootDirs = //... code to find root directories

    for (File f : rootDirs) { // find in root...
       scan(f);
    }

    Log.i("files", "" + files.size());
    Log.i("dir", "" + dir.size());


}

 public void scan (File path) {

    for (File f : path.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            files.add(f);
        }
        else {
            dir.add(f);
            scan(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to add some code to my edited version at //... code to find root directories: declare rootDirs as an empty list, then do something like for(File f : root.listFiles()) { if(f.isDirectory()) rootDirs.add(f); }

Comment: If I set first directory (not/sdcard ) for example folder "tree" with other folders and files inside it's work. But if root is "/sdcard" he find about 3 folders and "dead inside". write NullPointerException. Try find problem. Write later. Thanks....

Comment: for(File f : root.listFiles()) {
         if (f.isFile()) {
       files.add(f);
      }
      else {
       rootDirs.add(f);
      }
        }

Comment: he crash after folder "bugreports" =)

Comment: on folder .android_secure -> crash, write NullPointerException,but if set root on "/mnt/sdcard/My Files" work... Can't understand what's wrong

Comment: Maybe help someone. If scaning sdcard and try find all files, need find file ".android_secure" and remove from find list. Bacause when you try get access to this file, app crash!!! It's file with data about your sdCard and you can't get access without root access